# Symbolic matrix calculation

Tags: matrix, symbolic, operators

I have question about a matrix calculation like $\mathbf{b}^{t}\,\Sigma\,\mathbf{b}$, where $\Sigma$ is a 7 by 7 matrix, and $\mathbf{b}$ is vector of 7 elements, and each element in the vector $\mathbf{b}$ or $\Sigma$ is a symbolic formula,

For example, the (i, j)-th element of $\Sigma$ could have the form $\Sigma_{i,j}=ab+c+u+m$.

How can I do this calculation in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to use the "list" data structure in mathematica. Say, $\Sigma$ is a two by two matrix. In Mathematica, you just input

```
Sigma = {{x+y, m+n}, {x+y-w, m-n.l}}
```

Similarly

```
b={u,v}
```

Then, $b\Sigma b^T$ is just

```
b.Sigma.Transpose[b,{1}]
```

Hope it works for you.